# removing autoreleased UIWebview results in crash

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have a view containing a subview which in turn contains a UIWebview.

the subview is allocated and autoreleased

```
theController = [[[viewContainer alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewContainer" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]  autorelease];
```

The content for the webview is loaded onViewDidLoad in the subview.

I can remove this subview with no problem - as long as the app didn't go to the background before! The webview contains a link - when the user clicks on it, the app goes to the background and Safari opens the link. So far, so good. When I return to the app now and try to remove the subview containing the webview, I get this error:

```
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x7f3e970: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
```

[Edit]

Didn't really find a solution, just a mere workaround (thanks to Jumhyn for the help!):

I added an NSNotification to the subview that holds the webview.
When I get the applicationDidBecomeActive-Notification, I just use the same NSURLrequest again that I use in the viewDidLoadMethod and reload the content of the webview.
Now I can safely remove the view without getting an error...

Very weird behaviour...

Comment: Perhaps the phone is running low on memory, and some of your objects are being deallocated to avoid terminating your app entirely. You will need to check if they've been removed and re-create them when your app activates. It's a complicated topic that will need a fair bit of research into the available API's to simplify this process. You can take away a lot of the pain by enabling ARC. You can use the iOS Simulator's "simulate low memory warning" feature to debug these problems on your mac, which has gigabytes of available RAM.

Comment: Low memory can't be the issue - apart from a few graphics and a few views, there's nothing (I checked with Instruments)...

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer since I wasn't sure. It's just the first thing I would have tried. Perhaps you should post your solution as an answer, and accept it. It's perfectly fine to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

You really only want to use `autorelease` when you arent going to be using the object for an extended period of time. Instead, use an instance variable to hold your view controller, and `release` it in the dealloc method. Also, you can convert your project to ARC, which removes the need for `retain` and `release` calls entirely.

Comment: ARC??? Is there really garbage-collection now?
I'm gonna try and remove the autorelease-part

Comment: It isn't quite garbage collection, its a compiler feature that will essentially insert the essential retain/release calls.

Comment: thanks for the update on ARC...

The removal of the autorelease didn't help - still get the same error :(

Comment: Alright, well the error message seems to be complaining about the thread you're messing with the web view from. Any reason why that would change?

Comment: No idea. I just present a webpage in the webview, click on a link on this page, open safari, reopen the map... I don't do anything with the webview in between...

Comment: That's what the debugger spits out:

1   WebThreadLock
2   -[UIWebDocumentView clearWKFirstResponder]
3   -[UIWebDocumentView resignFirstResponder]
4   -[UIWebBrowserView resignFirstResponder]
5   -[UIView(Hierarchy) _removeFirstResponderFromSubtree]
6   __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview

Comment: ok - this is odd - I just added a notification for when the app goes to background and becomes active. In the didBecomeActive-Notification, I added the same Web-Request again. Now I can remove the view with no crash...?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5485/discussion-between-jumhyn-and-swissdude)